# ArcPad custom edit form validation behaviour

Tags: coordinates, arcpad, geography, vbscript

I have a custom ArcPad form, which includes the geography tab.  Users use this tab to update coordinates using the GPS.  When user press OK in the edit form, I want to first check that they have not moved the coordinates of a point beyond a set distance.
However, when I try to get the coordinates in VBS, from an event, it does not give me updated coordinates, only the coordinates that existed when the form was opened!

Here is the VBS Sub to grab the coordinates:

```
Sub SubCheckCoords()

  Dim msg
  Dim newXC, newYC, newZC
  newXC = EditForm.Fields.Shape.X
  newYC = EditForm.Fields.Shape.Y
  newZC = EditForm.Fields.Shape.Z

  msg = "NEW X "&newXC&" Y "&newYC&" Z"&newZC
  MsgBox(msg)


End Sub
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to get the current coordinates that are stored in the geography tab - before the form is closed?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the onFeatureAdded event and added code to pick up the coordinates using the thisevent.layer.name and thisevent.bookmark

```
strTempLayer = thisevent.layer.name
application.map.layers(strTempLayer).records.bookmark =  thisevent.bookmark
set tempShape= application.map.layers(strTempLayer).records.fields.shape
application.map.layers(strTempLayer).records.fields("XVal").value = tempShape.x
application.map.layers(strTempLayer).records.fields("YVal").value = tempShape.y
application.map.layers(strTempLayer).records.fields("ZVal").value = tempShape.z
application.map.layers(strTempLayer).records.update
```

Alternatively(Just adding I have just found from some old code..) which would validate that a field was edited.

```
if len(thisevent.object.pages("PAGE1").Controls("fieldname").value)= 0 then
    do stuff
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for that - It seems that is the only way I can pick up the new coordinates.  However, once the form is closed it is later than I wanted, since I want to warn the user about the distance the new point is from the old one.

Comment: You could use the GPS.x and GPS.y which would be inherently different to what is stored but they are always accessible..